Why is my JAGS output starting from 1000 not 0?
I am currently trying to use JAGS to do Bayesian analysis on the LakeHuron dataset on R. I cant seem to understand why when I plot the traceplots my iterations start from 1000 and run to 2000 even though I havent specified any burn in period?
I'm pretty new to all this so any help would be appreciated

library(rjags)


modelstring <- "
model {
alpha ~ dbeta(2, 5)
mu ~ dexp(0.01)
tau ~ dexp(10)
sd = pow(tau, -1)
for (i in 2:N) {
x[i] ~ dnorm(mu + alpha * (x[i - 1] - mu), tau)
}
}
"


jags_data <- list(x = LakeHuron, N = length(LakeHuron))

model <- jags.model(
  textConnection(modelstring),
  data = jags_data,
  n.chains = 4
)

samples <- coda.samples(model = model, variable.names = c("alpha", "mu", "tau"), n.iter = 1000)

plot(samples)

I'm expecting it to start from 0 and run to n.iter=1000 but it starts from 2000. You can see this by running summary(samples).

It's not exactly burn-in, but rjags::jags.model uses n.adapt = 1000 by default.

Thank you! I didnt realise that- makes sense now! I was getting so confused where my first 1000 iterations were going !!
